# Contents loaded with Ajax lose style

Tags: php, sql, ajax, jquery

I've create a page that load 10 elements and at the bottom of the page I've placed the classic button "load more" to load 10 more elements.

The problem is with jQuery, the style given by :nth-child() property doesn't work for the next 10 elements and so on.

Is there a solution to solve this problem?

E.g.:

File main.js

```
$("#main_content > p:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("small-product-wrapper");
$("#main_content > p:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass("small-product-wrapper");
```

File example.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#more_button').click(function(){

    loaded_messages += 10;

    $('#loading').ajaxSend(function() {
      $("#loading").stop(true,true).fadeIn().delay(200).fadeOut();
    });

    var dati = "twitterpagination/get_messages/" + loaded_messages;
    $.ajax({
      url:'twitterpagination/get_messages/' + loaded_messages,
      type: 'get',
      data: dati,
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
    $.get(dati, function(data){
      $("#main_content").append(data);
    });

    if(loaded_messages >= num_messages - 10) {
      $("#more_button").hide();
    }
      },
      error: function() {
    // do nothing 
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>

<div id="main">
  <?php
  foreach($latest_messages as $message) {
    echo '<p>'.$message->message .'</p>';
  }
  ?>
  <div id="more_button">more</div>
</div>
```

File loaded by Ajax url:

```
<?php
  foreach($latest_messages as $message) {
    echo '<p>'.$message->message .'</p>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file loaded by ajax:

```
<?php
  foreach($latest_messages as $message) {
    echo '<p class="small-product-wrapper">'.$message->message .'</p>';
  }
?>
```

Add the style to the returned P tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-run those 2 jQuery lines right after the new html is added from your AJAX.

```
success: function() {
    $.get(dati, function(data){

        $("#main_content").append(data);
        // here
        $("#main_content > p:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("small-product-wrapper");
        $("#main_content > p:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass("small-product-wrapper");
    });
}
```

This is because those original lines are run only once when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you load new content with Ajax the only way to have the style automatically assigned to it it's to give it a class and have that class style defined in css.

If you don't do that, you have to assign the style again in the callback function of the ajax call.